# Tic Tac Toe using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have created a Tic Tac Toe game using Javascript. Live demo can be seen [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Trolstover/0gqpeqL1/6/)

The code works fine but it has a little bug. When I click on the canvas, the image is drawn and everything works fine. But as I click on canvas, I invoke the  `superclick()` function which takes random path that hasn't been clicked on yet and draws set picture (O or X) on set position.

```
function superclick() {
    var filt = paths.filter(function(x) {
        return x.avaible == true;

    });
    var rand = filt[getRandomIntInclusive(0, paths.length - 1)];

    /*var evt = new MouseEvent("click", {
        view: window,
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        clientX: (canvas.offsetLeft + rand.x)+5,
        clientY: (canvas.offsetTop + rand.y)+5

    });
    canvas.dispatchEvent(evt)*/
    ctx.drawImage(turn[turns],rand.x,+ rand.y);
    score[turns] += rand.id;
    rand.avaible = false;
     turns = turns == "x" ? "o" : "x";

}
```

The problem here is that sometimes this function is invoked, and sometimes it isn't. When it isn't invoked it throws an error "Cannot read property 'x' of undefined", andI can't understand why. When I try to `console.log` set random path x it works. Did I miss something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're getting a random number between 0 and paths.length (so 0 and 8), but youre using that index to access "filt[]" which is only those squares that haven't been filled in.  So you might try to get the 8th element of "filt[]" when only 4 remain.

Try

```
var rand = filt[getRandomIntInclusive(0, filt.length - 1)];
```

This will make the max random number you grab proportional to the number of remaining spaces.

Comment: Oh , i seriously overlooked  this thing... thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Your "filt" variable is an array of object that begins with (at game launch) with 9 items -- one for each square. You are filtering the items as you go based on "avaible" (sic) squares.

Since the length of the paths array does not change (9), getting a random index (via 'getRandomIntInclusive') based on the range 1..9 returns an out of bound error because the length of the filt array is reduced on every turn.

What you want to do is change:

```
var rand = filt[getRandomIntInclusive(0, paths.length - 1)];
```

To:

```
var rand = filt[getRandomIntInclusive(0, filt.length - 1)];
```

...and you should be in a happy place.